# Windows XP Create Console Shortcuts for Applications

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, shortcuts, environment-variables, mingw

I have become a fervent console user since I began using the linux shell in my daily workflow.

I want to be able to call `"C:\Program Files\Application\Application.exe"` as `application` from the command line where the application is any arbitrary application. I know that I can use the `PATH` environment variable for this; however, I would prefer not to pollute my environment variable space more than it should be (since I have over 10 applications that I would like to create shortcuts for).

---

Edit: Should have mentioned earlier that I would also like the shortcuts to be compatible with MinGW as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aliases are available for the NT Command Prompt through the doskey command:

```
doskey word="%ProgramFiles%\Windows NT\Accessories\wordpad.exe" $*
```

You may now use the alias instead of the (full) name of the executable:

```
word %SystemDrive%\boot.ini
```

Comment: FYI, this works for any program that uses Win32 Console windows – not just `cmd.exe`. (My guess for MinGW is `doskey/exename=bash.exe`.)

Answer (score 2):

Create a folder, e.g. `C:\apps`, and place links to your applications there.

Add that folder to your `%PATH%`.

Then, change `%PATHEXT%` so you don't have to type the `.lnk` extension every time:

```
set PATHEXT=%PATHEXT%;.lnk
```

(You can edit environment variables in *System* in Control Panel)

Comment: .lnk files don't work for MinGW.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could put shortcuts (or batch files that simply 'call') to those applications in %systemroot%